# How do I get the list of providers from Dynamics 365 FO via an .NET core API

Tags: azure, api, .net-core, azureservicebus, dynamics-365-operations

So far, using Azure service bus, I have managed to get data from purchase orders, payment logs, invoices, etc.

But my API was waiting that one of these events to happen. But now we need to do an active search and show all providers registered in dynamics.

So far the ways we found to get some information from dynamics were: MS Flow, Azure Logic Apps and the Azure service bus. But it all depends on an event within Dynamics 369 FO so that we can receive some information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the tools in Azure (which are fantastic in some scenarios), have you considered interacting directly with the OData endpoints directly exposed by the D365FO application? You can create custom data entities using MorphX/x++ and expose them as an RESTful OData endpoints (JSON format returned). There are also hundreds of out of the box data entities that are exposed without needing custom ones created.

Learn more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/odata

and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/build-consuming-data-entities

and code samples here: https://github.com/microsoft/Dynamics-AX-Integration